# Proof: weakly convergent sequence is bounded

Tags: weak-convergence, hahn-banach-theorem

In class we had to proof:

Let $X$ be normed vector space.
If $(x_n)_n$ is a weakly convergent sequence in $X$ it follows that $(x_n)_n$ is bounded.

While I unterstand the proof we did in class (use of isometric canonical embedding and Hahn-Banach) I want to also check an other approach with a followup Separation Corollary of Hahn-Banach:

Let $X$ be a non-trivial normed vector space.
Then for any $x ∈ X$ there is a functional $x^∗ ∈ X^∗$ with $||x^∗|| = 1$ and
with $x^∗(x) = ||x||$.

Proof for which I need validation:

If $(x_n)_n$ converges weakly to $x$ in $X$, then for any $n$ we have that $x_n - x$ is also in $X$.
Therefore, by the separation Corollary there exists a functional $x^*$ in $X^*$ such that $x^*(x_n-x)=||x_n-x||$.

If we take norm on both sides we get

$||x_n-x||=||x^*(x_n-x)||$

And using linearity of $x^*$:

$||x_n-x||=||x^*(x_n-x)||=||x^*(x_n)-x^*(x)||$

Since $(x_n)_n$ converges weakly to $x$ we have that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $N\leq n$ we have

$||x^*(x_n)-x^*(x)||<\epsilon$

and hence also

$||x_n-x||=||x^*(x_n)-x^*(x)||<\epsilon$

Therefore, $x_n$ converges to $x$ and hence $x_n$ must be bounded.

Comment: A problem is, $x^{\ast } (x_n -x)=\Vert x_n -x\Vert $ for one $n$ does not mean that it holds for all $m\geq N$.

Comment: For each n there exists $x_n^*\in X^*$such that $x_n^*(x-x_n)=\|x-x_n\|.$ There does not necessarily exist $x^*\in X^*$ such that $\forall n\,(x^*(x-x_n)=\|x-x_n\|) $ and often there isn't.

Comment: If correct this would be a proof that any weakly convergent sequence is actually convergent in norm. That should be a clue that  it must be wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1).$ The canonical embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$ with $x\to x^{**}\in X^{**},$ where $x^{**}(y)=y(x)$ for all $y\in X^*$ and $x\in X$, is an isometry. That is, $\|x\|=\|x^{**}\|.$

Proof: By the Hahn-Banach Theorem, for  $x\in X$  the functional $y$ on the vector subspace generated  by $\{x\}$, such that $y(x)=\|x\|$, extends to some $y_x\in X^*$ with $\|y_x\|=1.$

Now $\|x^{**}\|=\sup \{|x^{**}(y)|:\|y\|=1\}=\sup \{|y(x)|:\|y\|=1\}\le \|x\|.$

But $\|x^{**}\|\ge |x^{**}(y_x)|=|y_x(x)|=\|x\|.$

$(2).$ The Uniform Boundedness Principle(UBP). If $B$ is a Banach  space and $F\subset B^*$ such that $\sup_{f\in F}\,|f(b)|<\infty$ for each $b\in B$ then $\sup_{f\in F}\,\|f\|<\infty.$

$(3).$ If $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a weakly convergent sequence in $X$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}y(x_n)$ exists for each $y\in X^*.$ A convergent series of scalars (i.e. members of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) is bounded.

So $\sup \{|x^{**}_n(y)|:n\in \Bbb N\} =\sup \{|y(x_n)|:n\in \Bbb N\}<\infty$ for each $y\in X^*.$

Applying the UBP with $B=X^*$ and $F=\{x_n^{**}: n\in \Bbb N|\}$ we have $$\infty>\sup \{\|x^{**}_n\|:n\in \Bbb N\}=\sup \{\|x_n\|:n\in \Bbb N \}.$$

Comment: Hahn-Banach, UBP, and the Closed Graph Theorem are the 3 "fundamental theorems" of Banach-space theory.